# How to print a string in color in ARM32

Tags: assembly, arm

Hello i'm new to assembly language and I want to print a Color string line in ARM32 but can't find information on how to do so. Here's the code I have:

```
.data
personal_str:    .asciz "First name: Guillermo.\r\nLast name: Morel."
.text
.global_start
_start:
 mov r0, #1
 ldr r1, =personal_str
 mov r2, #81
 mov r7, #4
 swi #0
 mov r7, #1
 mov r0, #0
 swi #0
```

How can I implement color to the above code?, Thanks in advance.

Comment: That depends on whatever environment you are in, and how it allows you to set color, if at all. You might try to use [ansi color](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#Colors) codes, and hope they work.

Comment: Its to print int in console on a Raspberry Pi 3 using Raspbian. Can you give me an example on how to implement ansi color codes to the above code?

Comment: I have linked you to wikipedia. Just embed the code in your string. Depends on your terminal if they will work or not.